# How to delete some similar rows from a table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, Countries and Sums:

```
+------+---------+
| code | country |
+------+---------+
| 01   | France  |
| 02   | Germany |
| 02   | Austria |
| 03   | Belgium |
| 04   | Belgium |
| 04   | Spain   |
| 05   | Italy   |
+------+---------+

+------+-----+
| code | sum |
+------+-----+
| 01   | 500 |
| 02   | 400 |
| 03   | 300 |
| 04   | 200 |
+------+-----+
```

I want to create a table code-sum-country. It's very easy of course, but I need to have exactly the same number of rows as in the table Sums.

```
+------+-----+---------+
| code | sum | country |
+------+-----+---------+
| 01   | 500 | France  |
| 02   | 400 | Austria |
| 02   | 400 | Germany |
| 03   | 300 | Belgium |
| 04   | 200 | Spain   |
| 04   | 200 | Belgium |
+------+-----+---------+
```

I want to have in the above table unique code values. So I need to remove some of them, it doesn't matter which one. My goal is to have only one row with the same code. For example the row

```
| 04   | 200 | Spain   |
```

can remain or be deleted.
How can I do that?

Comment: your question is not so clear.. you want to remove records, but what is your criteria.. and what is expected final output for this sample data..

Comment: My goal is to have only one row with the same code.

Comment: so 'Spain' in your example could be whatever of the countries, because I understand that it is actually about code and sum? If yes, I suggest a group by and a max or min on code.

Comment: Sums has 4 rows. You say you want exactly the same number of rows as in the table Sums, and list 6 rows...? Am I missing something?

Comment: jarlh: the last table is what I get when I simply connect these two tables. It's not that what I want. I want a table with 4 rows. So for code 02 there could be Austria OR Germany and for code 04 Spain OR Belgium (one of them of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE
FROM code_sum_country
WHERE code in
 (SELECT code
  FROM code_sum_country
  GROUP BY code
  HAVING COUNT (code) > 1) 
AND country NOT IN
 (SELECT MIN(country)
  FROM code_sum_country
  GROUP BY code
  HAVING COUNT (code) > 1)
```

This will retain the country whose name is minimum in alphabetical order.

Change `MIN(country)` to `MAX(country)` if you want to retain the maximal ones.

Hope it helps :）

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query `sums` and get one arbitrary country, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*,
       (select top 1 c.country
        from countries as c
        where s.code = c.code
       ) as country
from sums as s;
```

Comment: This is very helpful query. I tried in on above tables and it works. But I have a problem with my original table. I added `INTO new_table` to your query and ran it on Access. After five minutes new table was not created. My table has about 20k rows. Why it takes so long?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question in such a way that the result is actually about code and sum, and an example of country is desired. Probably to give more meaning to your results and which country is actually returned is irrelevant... I therefore suggest a group by and a max or min on code, and max or min on country. See beneath.

PS: possibly it could be more usefull to define a different kind of name that is more meaningfull than country. But that is kind of bluntly to say without more info :).

```
select
min(code) as code
,[sum]
,min(country) as country
from TableAA
group by sum
```